# Cast / Convert a Text column to String while creating a VIEW in SQLite

Tags: sqlite, types, casting

I need to cast a field while creating a VIEW of a table in a SQLite database:

A basic example would be:

Table1 {
field1 TEXT,
field2 TEXT,
... }

```
CREATE VIEW ViewFromTable as SELECT field1, cast (field2 as INTEGER) as fieldConverted  from Table1
```

where field2 is a TEXT column 
 I want to convert its content in the column fielConverted as INTEGER.

My real query has a case expresion as follows:

```
CREATE VIEW ViewFromTable AS
SELECT field1, 
CASE
WHEN field2 == "case1" THEN 1
WHEN field2 == "case2" THEN 2
ELSE 3
END
as fieldConverted 
FROM Table1
```

However, I get that Type of the column in the VIEW is TEXT for the column fieldConverted and I want it to be INTEGER

Any idea about the sintaxis with my query? Any other way to do this conversion? Is this possible?
Thanks in advance

Comment: What piece of software tells you that a view's column has a type?

Comment: if I  do PRAGMA table_info (table1) , it gives the TYPE.

Comment: But not for views. What other software is this? How does it try to get the column type?

Answer (score 0):

Expressions are expressions, there is no difference:

```
SELECT field1, CAST(CASE ... END AS INTEGER) AS fieldConverted ...
```

However, SQLite uses dynamic typing; columns do not have a type, and this is unlikely to change anything.

Comment: I need the views to be used by other software, so that I need that the column of the view has INTEGER type. (If not the hole thing doesn't works). I could create another INTEGER column in the original table and then operate with it. Is there any other way without extra columns ?